# Using the same cache in multiple classes

Tags: java, spring

Within my application, I have two different, existing services (that do not directly communicate) that need to access some of the same information (storing new entries and retrieving existing entries) that is stored in a cache.  I've currently got the cache in its own class (B) but am unsure how to get the two classes, C and D, to access it as well.  Due to the complexity of the application and how these services operate, I am unable to have another class (A) instantiate the cache (B), and pass that reference to C and D.  Are there any existing design patterns or implementations I could follow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as explained in the  [spring docs][1]
[1]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html
inject  CacheManager  use cacheManager to get and put with key.

```
@Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
```

var cache = cacheManager.getCache("cacheName");

cache.get(key);